# SQL (via phpMyAdmin)

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, sql-update

I want to do a Search and Replace in a WordPress posts table, but conditional on the type of posts 
This is what I have got, and SELECTing works but I am not sure about replacing 'old title' with 'new prefix old title'

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` 
WHERE `post_title` REGEXP '^old title' 
  AND `post_type` = 'download' 
set 'post_title' = replace( 'post_title', 'old title', 'new prefix old title');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `set` clause should come before the `where` clause. Also, `post_title` is a column name, not a string literal, so you shouldn't use single quotes (`'`):

```
UPDATE `wp_posts`
SET    `post_title` = REPLACE(`post_title`, 'old title', 'new prefix old title')
WHERE  `post_title` REGEXP '^old title' AND `post_type` = 'download'
```

Comment: Many thanks for the assist @Mureinik, that worked as requested.

(I'd have replied earlier but didn't get notified of your rapid response.)

One question I was left with was, you are distinguishing between ' and ` ?
(Apostrophe [single quote] ' vs Grave accent ` when referring to table references like column names?)

Comment: @BrianMilnes yes - quotes (') denote string literals. Grave accents (`) can be used to escape object names, like columns and tables